# Stop BitsTransfer job on Powershell close

Tags: powershell

I've wrapped a synchronous `Start-BitsTransfer` call in a `try-catch-finally` block as follows:

```
$BitsJob

TRY
{
    $BitsJob = Start-BitsTransfer ...
}
CATCH
{
    WriteErrorLog ...
    THROW 
}
FINALLY
{
    Remove-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $BitsJob
}
```

However, the `finally` block does not run when I close the Powershell window, and the transfer continues in the background.

Why isn't this working, and how can I correctly cancel the job when Powershell is closed?

EDIT:

I've additionally tried the following to no avail:

```
$BitsJob

Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.Exiting -Action {
    Remove-BitsTransfer -BitsJob $BitsJob
}

$BitsJob = Start-BitsTransfer ...
```

There is an [outstanding Powershell bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8000) per `PowerShell.Exiting` not executing when the window is closed using the X button. So it may be there is not currently a good way to do this.

Comment: If you close the powershell session that started the bitstransfer you are cancelling the transfer aren't you?

Comment: No so. From Microsoft docs: "BITS continues to transfer files after an application exits if the user who initiated the transfer remains logged on and a network connection is maintained."

Comment: I see, so it initiates a new process. However, from what I can tell, if you close the session that started this try / catch / finally then the logic is gone, it will never reach the catch or finally blocks.